# Unable to override Styled Component in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a `BaseComponent` in one file, which is made up of several other components and I am exporting that component. The highest level of the  `BaseComponent` has a wrapper that is responsible for the margin. When I export it and try to overwrite some of the styles with

```
 //other file

const BaseComponentWrapper = styled.div`
  margin: 10px
`

const export BaseComponent = () => {
  return (
      <BaseComponentWrapper>
          Some other stuff in the middle
      </ BaseComponentWrapper >
}
```

```
import { BaseComponent } from otherfile

const ModifiedBaseComponent = styled(BaseComponent)`
  margin: 0 px;
`
```

The margin does not change to `0px` for my `ModifiedBaseComponent`.

The only way I have been able to change the margin is to take the class produced by styled components from the browser and plug it in under the wrapper css for example

```
const BaseComponentWrapper {
  .etbykw {
     margin: 0px;
  }
}
```

From what I am aware of at the very least this code below should work but it also does not

```
const BaseComponentWrapper {
  > ${ModifiedBaseComponent} {
     margin: 0px;
  }
}
```

From what I have seen on other questions there is something about a className prop that might be useful but I am unable to understand this. I know it's a specificity problem of some kind but I am really struggling to fully understand this and the code that works is not very readable from an outside party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To style a commonly component, you must pass the className property.

In the example below, the BaseComponent takes a className and passes it to the BaseComponentWrapper.

Now you can style your BaseComponent.

Docs: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components

```
const BaseComponentWrapper = styled.div`
  margin: 10px;
`;

export const BaseComponent = ({ className, children }) => {
  return (
    <BaseComponentWrapper className={className}>
      {children}
    </BaseComponentWrapper>
  );
};
```